# Use variable in widget build in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I started programming in flutter, but I can't pass a variable to a new class. I was able to do that on my other codes. Now I don't know what to do.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:google_ml_kit/google_ml_kit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BilgiEkrani extends StatefulWidget {
  final String sonuc;
  final double oran;
  const BilgiEkrani({required this.sonuc, required this.oran});
  @override
  _BilgiEkrani createState() => _BilgiEkrani(sonuc, oran);
}

class _BilgiEkrani extends State<BilgiEkrani> {
  _BilgiEkrani(String sonuc, double oran);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      toolbarHeight: 20,
      backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
      title: **sonuc**,
//Undefined name 'sonuc'.
//Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: use `widget.sonuc` instead of just `sonuc`

Comment: Just use `widget.sonuc` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120032/13997210)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you like to use variables inside `State` class that is coming from main class that extends `StatefulWidget`, you need to use `widget.variableName`. In your case, to use `sonuc` String inside state, you need to use `widget.sonuc`.

`title:` takes a widget, therefor you need to wrap `sonic` with widget then pass it there. For String, simply use `Text` widget.

```
title: Text(widget.sonuc),
```

You can learn more about [widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to pass by the constructor as the other widgets do.

```
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? parameter;
  final String requiredParameter;

  CustomWidget({this.parameter, required this.requiredParameter});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  ...
  }
}
```

Now you can use this widget like this:

**CustomWidget(requiredParameter: 'Some value')**