# Why can't I access my variable in the widget?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, widget

I'm learning flutter. I'm beginner in flutter.
I'm progressing by watching the video. At now, I'm learning the stateful widget. I identified a `name` variable in the stateful widget then I wanna access that name variable in the widget like this
 `Text("${Widget.name} count : $counter"),`. But I got this error "**The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Widget'**." How can I solve this problem?

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {

  final String name ;
  Counter(this.name);

  @override
  _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  
  int counter = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Text("${Widget.name} count : $counter"),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The name widget in `Widget.name` should be in a small letter. So you should be able to access it like this `widget.name`.

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120032/13997210) hope its help to you. just use `widget.name`

Comment: If your problem is solved by answer please upvote it,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just typo error, you need to use `widget.variableName`.

On your snippet `Widget.name` will be `widget.name`.

`Text("${widget.name} count : $counter"),`