# I wanna call a value from function based widget from another class in the same dart.file into a Text widget

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have this class called VarianKemasan which has a function called totalBelanjaKemasan

```
class VarianKemasan extends StatefulWidget {
  final productDetail;

  const VarianKemasan({Key? key, this.productDetail}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VarianKemasanState createState() => _VarianKemasanState();
}

class _VarianKemasanState extends State<VarianKemasan> {

totalBelanjaKemasan() {
    Text(
        "${GlobalFunctions().rupiah(widget.productDetail['price'] * _parseCounter())}");
    }
```

and wanna call the value that function has into a Text widget in another class

```
class ProductDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final productDetail;

  const ProductDetailPage({Key? key, this.productDetail}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductDetailPageState createState() => _ProductDetailPageState();
}

class _ProductDetailPageState extends State<ProductDetailPage> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      body: Container(
             child: Text(
                    "called value here",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Color(0xff31708F)),
                    )
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Try below code hope its help to you. refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120032/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494291/13997210) also for that used `widget.productDetail`

**your VarianKemasan Class:**

```
class VarianKemasan extends StatefulWidget {
  final product = 'Product Data';

  @override
  _VarianKemasanState createState() => _VarianKemasanState();
}

class _VarianKemasanState extends State<VarianKemasan> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("App Bar"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ProductDetailPage(
                  productDetail: widget.product,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Text(
              'Ok',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Your `ProductDetailPage` class**

```
class ProductDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final productDetail;
  ProductDetailPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.productDetail,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
        );

  @override
  _ProductDetailPageState createState() => _ProductDetailPageState();
}

class _ProductDetailPageState extends State<ProductDetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("App Bar"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            widget.productDetail,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Color(0xff31708F)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't help.

Comment: what do you exact want

Comment: i want to call the value from class VarianKemasan to Text in class ProductDetailPage

Comment: Hello @AdhityaResadikara please check my updated answer